# How are FRW metric and Minkowski metric physically different?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, diffeomorphism-invariance

According to GR, matrices are coordinate invariant. Does this mean we can transform FRW metric to Minkowski metric with a coordinate transformation like 
$$dx'=dx\cdot a(t), dy' = dy\cdot a(t), dz' = dz\cdot a(t)$$

If yes, then why do we say that the two represent different spacetimes? If no, then why not?

Comment: No, GR doesn't say matrices are coordinate invariant. Tensors are invariants, and 2nd rank tensors are frequently written as matrices, but the representation, i.e. the terms in the matrix, are dependant on the coordinates chosen. For example the Minkowski and Rindler metric are the same object, but look wildly different when written as matrices because they use different coordinate systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To decide if two metrics are related by a change of frame and/or coordinate transformation is called the *equivalence problem*. It can be solved using the [Cartan-Karlhede algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Karlhede_algorithm).

Given a metric $g$ expressed in some coordinates $x_i$, the algorithm computes a set of invariantly defined curvature invariants expressed as functions of $x_i$. For example, the scalar curvature $R = R(x_i)$. To decide if two metrics are *equivalent*, compute this set for both metrics and consider the set of equations \begin{align*}
R(x_i) & = R'(y_i) \\
\Psi_1(x_i) & = \Psi_1'(y_i) \\
& \vdots
\end{align*}
where primed quantities refer to the second metric, which is expressed in the coordinates $y_i$. (The full set of equations is typically much larger, but also typically many of the equations are $0 = 0$.)

If you can solve for the $y_i$ as functions of the $x_i$ or vice versa (or just show that a solution exists), you have established that the metrics are equivalent. If it is clear that a solution does not exist (for example, one of the equations could be $1 = 0$) the metrics are not equivalent.

---

For the particular case of the FLRW metrics compared to the Minkowski metric, one of the equations is $$0 = (k + \dot{a}^2)$$
where $k$ and $a$ are the quantities that appear in the FLRW line element
and another one is $$0 = k+\dot{a}^2 + a\ddot{a}$$
Combining these it must be that $a$ is a constant and $k = 0$. This corresponds to the Minkowski metric with the spatial part expressed in spherical coordinates with the radial coordinates being scaled a factor $a$ relative to each other.

This conclusion can also be reached from the [Friedmann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations). For the Minkowski metric $\rho - \Lambda / \kappa = p + \Lambda / \kappa = 0$ and the Friedmann equations imply $k = 0$, $a$ constant.

Comment: If you combine the two equations you wrote you get $a\ddot a=0$ which holds for instance when $\dot a = \pm 1$ in which case $k=-1$ allows both invariants you list to be zero. I remember the metrics are different, so you might have a mistake somewhere. You also have kappas and k so if you mean them to be different you might want to go into more detail about them.

Comment: @Robin-Ekman I have written a paper which uses Cartan-Karlhede algorithm. Can you please take a look and let me know if I made some mistake? The paper is available at http://vixra.org/abs/1511.0047

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to demand that $dx' = a(t)\ dx$. Suppose that your coordinate transformation was of the form $x' = x'(x)$. Then you would have $dx' = \frac{dx'}{dx}\ dx$, but $\frac{dx'}{dx}$ would have to be a function of $x$ only, and so it couldn't be $a(t)$. Now suppose we tried to fix that by doing a transformation $x'  = x'(x,t)$. Now $dx' = \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\ dx + \frac{\partial x'}{\partial t}\ dt$, and we get a $dt$ term which will mess things up. So your proposed coordinate transformation is not actually one.

The moral here is that defining a transformation by asking for a corresponding transformation of the differentials is only guaranteed to work when a single variable is involved each time. For example, if for some reason you wanted a new coordinate $x'$ such that $dx' = x^2\ dx$, then you could simply integrate to find $x' = \frac13 x^3$. But in your case, if you're going to demand that $dx' = f\ dx + g\ dt$ where both $f$ and $g$ depend on $(x,t)$ and (here) $g=0$, then this is only realizable if $\partial_x g = \partial_t f$, which is not true in your proposed transformation.